# Constant velocity while still being able to apply an impulse

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, physics

I am making a game where as the main sprite/player moves constantly, he/she needs to jump through barriers.

I need help with how to set a constant velocity for my moving sprite. When I try and do this in the SpriteKit update function, I can’t apply an impulse to jump whenever the user taps the screen.

Here is my code. I commented the places where I am having trouble:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */
    if (gameStarted == false) {
        gameStarted = true

        mainSprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        mainSprite.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        let spawn = SKAction.runBlock({
            () in

            self.createWalls()
        })


        let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5)

        let spawnDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])

        let spawnDelayForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnDelay)

        self.runAction(spawnDelayForever)

        let distance = CGFloat(self.frame.height + wallPair.frame.height)

        let movePipes = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -distance - 50, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.009 * distance)) // Speed up pipes

        let removePipes = SKAction.removeFromParent()

        moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([movePipes, removePipes])

    } else {
        if died == true {

        }
        else {
            mainSprite.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 20)) // TRYING TO APPLY AN IMPULSE TO MY SPRITE SO IT CAN JUMP AS IT MOVES
        }
    }



    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    updateSpritePosition()
    mainSprite.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(400, 0) // SETS A CONSTANT VELOCITY, HOWEVER I CAN NOT APPLY AN IMPULSE.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're overwriting the velocity in the `update` method. So even though you added an impulse, it gets immediately overwritten by code in the `update`. Try overwriting just the `dx` part of the velocity.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    updateSpritePosition()
    mainSprite.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(400, mainSprite.physicsBody?.velocity.dy)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :D <3